# Where should I put compiled binaries so that the would become searchable?

Tags: compiling, search

I'm compiling software from source. This software project doesn't come with an installer, so I just put the binary in `/usr/local/bin`, then I can start it from the terminal with a command

```
software &
```

Where should I put the binary so that it would become searchable in Ubuntu's? (Finder? search? thingy which is in the upper left corner by default)

Comment: Anywhere inside $PATH env variable. Do echo $PATH to find out. Alternatively, add that path to $PATH like this: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

They have to be in any directory included in the `PATH` environment variable. This is either done by copying it to a directory included in the PATH variable. My PATH looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/tigcc
```

Or you can add the directory with your binaries to the PATH location. For this, include the following line into `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`: (Put it at the end of the file; will work after logging out and in again)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/binaries
```

---

If you want to make it accessible in the application menu, you have to create a launcher for it either in `/usr/share/applications/` (for all users) or `~/.local/share/applications`.

This launcher has to be a textfile with the extension `.desktop`Look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) to find out how it works.  You may also duplicate an existing launcher, which makes things easier to you.

After saving it, make it executable: `chmod +x launcher.desktop` (put sudo if in `/usr/share/...`)

Comment: The binary is in the directory included in PATH, that's why I can start it from the terminal with `software &`, but it isn't searchable with Ubuntu search.

Answer (score 0):

It's not where you put the compiled binary that matters. What you need to do is [create a launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) for your application to show up and be searchable in the Unity dash. Also see the numerous answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/70254) for various alternative ways to create launchers.